# Sitecore 8: Adding a color widget to the Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor, sitecore8

As per subject - I noticed that, surprisingly enough, there is no default option in the Rich Text Editor to color the text. Does anyone knows how to do it?

I searched online for the past hour or so, and found a lot of mutually contradicting material, probably dating back to older versions.

Comment: Font and background colours are a bit 1990's. Use CSS Classes, narrow them down a specific set of corporate colours, it'll make mass changes in the future much easier.

Comment: That is a good suggestion and indeed we already have in place our defaults classes set to our corporate colors - but our Content Editors sometimes want the ability to override them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your buttons under:
*/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Toolbar 1*

For your situation you can copy these 2 items:

*/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Toolbar 2/Forecolor*

*/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Toolbar 2/Backcolor*

under:

*/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Toolbar 1*

P.S. It is in core database.

Comment: Thanks @Anton This will work but what if we want to add the forecolor as webedit button

Answer (score 3):

What I always do to give editors access to thing like that is work with css classes. You can attach a css file to the editor in the settings. The default value for "WebStylesheet" is "/default.css".

This way editors can alter some look & feel (e.g. change color) but in the boundaries that you decide. It also helps when you need to update. If css-classes were used the update is as easy as changing the css file. Otherwise all content has to be altered.